Can you cancel the branch cut in a Bessel K function?
This blog post points out that although the Bessel function $J_{\nu}(z)$ has a branch cut along the negative reals, $J_{\nu}(z)/z^{\nu}$ does not have such a branch cut. This is very convenient.
I am wondering if there is some elementary function which cancels the branch cut of the Bessel $K$ function, specifically $K_1(z)$, in a similar manner.

If you look at the symbol at singularity $0$ of $z^2F''+zF'-(z^2+1)F=0$ the ODE satisfied by $K_1$ you notice that it is $\pm 1$ (indicial equation at $0$ is $a(a-1)+a-1=0$ so $a= \pm 1$ and $I_1$ is an analytic solution corresponding to $a=1$ while $K_1$ is a solution corresponding to $-1$.
By the general theory of linear ODE's one can see that is of the form $K_1(z)=c/z+  f(z) \log z+ g(z)$ with $f,g$ analytic near $0$ and $c \ne 0$ and formulas can be given for those (eg $c=1, f(z)=\sum_{m \ge 0}\frac{z^{2m+1}}{2^{2m+1}m!(m+1)!}$) while $g$ is more complicated but can be found for example in Watson's classical treatise on Bessel functions at page $80$ equation $15$ (Internet Archive pdf at link) at page $80$ equation $15$.
So it is more complicated as the branch at zero of $K_1$ due to the logarithm cannot be immediately eliminated by a simple operation since both $f,g$ are nonvanishing
